# Gnosis safe-core-sdk : EthersAdapter is giving empty object

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I'm trying to use  safe-core-sdk on our Dapp but the EthersAdapter instance  creation is always giving empty object even the signer is getting from the provider is working fine [image]

Lib used : ether.js ^5.5.2 , "bnc-onboard": "^1.35.4",

Attaching console screenshot and code below

```
  const safeService = new SafeServiceClient(transactionServiceUrl);
        const onboard = initOnboard({
            address: setAddress,
            network: setNetwork,
            balance: setBalance,
            wallet: wallet => {
                setWallet(wallet);

                if (wallet.provider) {
                    console.info(`${wallet.name} is connected`);

                    const ethersProvider = new Web3Provider(wallet.provider);
                    console.log(ethersProvider.getSigner());
                    // signerAddress(ethersProvider.getSigner());
                    const ethersAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
                        ethers: ethers,
                        signer: ethersProvider.getSigner(0),
                    });
                    console.log(ethersAdapter);
                    setEthersAdaptor(ethersAdapter);
                    // provider = ethersProvider;
                    setProvider(ethersProvider);

                    window.localStorage.setItem("selectedWallet", wallet.name);
                } else {
                    // provider = null;

                    setProvider(false);
                    setWallet({});
                }
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see the methods inside EthersAdapter class if you expand it?

[image]

Comment: Yea receiving it , Thanks for the response !